# How to compute the variances of quotients of normal variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

$x$ and $y$ are independent normal random variables.  $z1=x/(x+y)$ and $z2=y/(x+y).$

How to obtain the variances for $z1$ and $z2$?

I understand through the delta method, $\operatorname{Var}(z1)$ can be approximated as

$$((Ey)^2 \operatorname{Var}(x)+(Ex)^2(\operatorname{Var}(x)+\operatorname{Var}(y)))/(E(x)+E(y))^4$$

and $\operatorname{Var}(z2)$ can be approximated as

$$((Ex)^2 \operatorname{Var}(y)+(Ey)^2(\operatorname{Var}(x)+\operatorname{Var}(y)))/(E(x)+E(y))^4.$$

Apparently, these two expressions would not be equal to each other but we know the variances of $z1$ and $z2$ are supposed to be equal based on their functional relationship with $x$ and $y.$  Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Let's solve this first for the case where $X$ and $Y$ are iid standard Normal variables.  (The question appears to assume $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed anyway, suggesting this is a good starting point.)

Because $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, the $Z_i$ are [exchangeable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/374997/919) and therefore also must be identically distributed.  Let their common variance be $\sigma^2$ and suppose for a moment it is finite.  Since $Z_1+Z_2=1$ is constant it has zero variance, allowing us to compute

$$0 =\operatorname{Var}(Z_1+Z_2) = 2\sigma^2 + 2 \operatorname{Cov}(Z_1,Z_2),$$

thereby deducing

$$\operatorname{Cov}(Z_1,Z_2) = -\sigma^2.$$

But, writing $\mu=E[Z_1] =E[Z_2]$ (whose finiteness is assured by the assumed finiteness of $\sigma^2$), algebra shows us

$$\eqalign{
\sigma^2 = -\operatorname{Cov}(Z_1,Z_2) &= -E[Z_1 Z_2] + \mu^2 \\
&= -E\left[\frac{XY}{(X+Y)^2}\right]  + \mu^2\\
&= -\frac{1}{4} E\left[\frac{(X+Y)^2 - (X-Y)^2}{(X+Y)^2}\right]  + \mu^2\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\left(-1 + E\left[\frac{(X-Y)^2}{(X+Y)^2}\right]\right) + \mu^2.
}$$

The numerator and denominator in that final fraction are *independent* because $(X-Y, X+Y)$ are jointly Normally distributed with zero covariance.  Since a multiple of the denominator $(X+Y)^2$ must therefore have a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution, and the density of that distribution in a neighborhood of $0$ is positive, [the ratio must have *infinite* variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/299765/919).

We are compelled to reject the original assumption that $\sigma^2$ is finite; and there is the answer: $\operatorname{Var}(Z_1) = \operatorname{Var}(Z_2) = \infty.$

---

It is straightforward to generalize these arguments to arbitrary independent Normal variables--the algebra gets a little messier, but the same principle applies: the ratios are random variables with infinite variances.

BTW, because the $Z_i$ sum to unity their means must either sum to unity or be undefined, whence $\mu=1/2$ (returning to the original simplified setting) or else $\mu$ is undefined.  This is a very general result, holding for *any* bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ have identical expectations $\mu.$

Comment: Isn't it the case that if $A$ and $B$ are a random variable whose joint density is nonzero everywhere in a neighborhood of the origin $0$, then $\frac AB$ does not have an expectation and so in the simplest viewpoint, one cannot even begin to _define_ the _variance_ of $\frac AB$? There exists no _mean_ of  $\frac AB$ from which we can compute deviations whose mean-square value is desired.

Comment: @Dilip It is unnecessary to define the mean to define a variance, because the variance of a random variable $X$ can be expressed in terms of the expectation of $(X_1-X_2)^2$ where the $X_i$ are independent copies of $X.$

Answer (score -1):

Following $$f'(t) = \frac{g'(t)h(t) - g(t)h'(t)}{h^2(t)}$$

$$\frac {\partial z_1} {\partial x} = \frac {x+y - x}{(x+y)^2} = \frac {y}{(x+y)^2}$$

$$\frac {\partial z_1} {\partial y} = \frac {- x}{(x+y)^2}$$

$$\frac {\partial z_2} {\partial x} = \frac {-y}{(x+y)^2}$$

$$\frac {\partial z_2} {\partial y} = \frac {x}{(x+y)^2}$$

So their variance are the same.

$$\mathrm{Var}(z_1) = \mathrm{Var}(z_2) \approx \frac {(\mathrm{E}(y))^2 \mathrm{Var}(x)+(\mathrm{E}(x))^2\mathrm{Var}(y)}{[\mathrm{E}(x)+\mathrm{E}(y)]^4}$$

This method is applicable when $\mathrm{E}(x) + \mathrm{E}(y)$ have a certain distance from 0.

Comment: You claim to be computing something that unfortunately it isn't even finite -- and your formula doesn't even make sense because its denominator is zero.  Thus, although you are correct that the variances are equal (and obviously so, due to the exchangeability of the $Z_i$), this derivation requires more subtlety.